# Gmaps4rails not working well with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I have a model where geolocating works fine, and pagination ( via limit/ offset ) like in kaminari and will_paginate, works fine. Separately. Together, however, they present me with this error.

```
Location.near(postcode, 5) # works fine

Location.all.page(1) # works fine

Location.near(postcode, 5).page(1) #gives me the following error...

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance